# JQuery .append line break in text area on hitting return

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to go to the next line after hitting the 'Enter' (keycode == 13) after entering some text. This works if you hit 'Enter' before you enter any text but not after. Here's some of my script

```
var keyPressedOnContactUsMessageHandler = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).append(" \n\n");
        if ($("#ContactUsMessage").focus()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        sendMessage();
        blockEnterKeyHandler(e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is probably that you have a `textarea` and are attempting to add content to it with `append`.  The HTML content of a `textarea` element is only relevant when the page is parsed. After that, the text contained is referred to by the `value` property. You should modify this instead.

```
this.value += '\n\n';
```

My guess is that your browser is being generous: if you modify the HTML before the `value` is altered, it modifies the `value` accordingly. It's better just to modify the `value` yourself.

---

Also, `$("#ContactUsMessage").focus()` will always return a truthy value. If you are trying to test whether the element is focused, use `is`:

```
if ($('#ContactUsMessage').is(':focus')) {
```

NB that this does not work in older browsers if you are using a version of jQuery before 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Also, after you fix that, this section

```
sendMessage();
blockEnterKeyHandler(e);
```

never gets reached because you always return something before it with this if statement

```
if($("#ContactUsMessage").focus()) {
      return false;
} else {
      return true;
}
```